# Is this a correct construction: "Up to some point in the past I was not aware"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How should I construct a sentence that would mean *Up to some time in the past I was not aware of something* (e.g., *Until a few days ago, I did not know that you arrived in the city.*)?

Is the sentence correct? Please suggest a few more equivalent sentences with better structure than this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> *Up until* a few days ago, I did not know that you arrived in the city.
>
> *Up until* a few days ago, I was not aware that you arrived in the city.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options to express your concept:

> I just learnt that you arrived in the city a few days ago.
>
> I was not aware that you arrived in the city a few days ago.
>
> I knew nothing about your arrival in the city till a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options to consider.

> - I *just found out* a few days ago that you arrived in the city.
> - *Prior to/up until* a few days ago, I had no idea that you had arrived in the city.

Another alternative (slightly different connotation):

> - I was *caught off guard* a few days ago after learning that you arrived in the city.